# How to span a column of jTable made using DefaultDataModel

Tags: java, swing

I would like to span my `jtable` columns but i fail. please help me.
I would like to span two columns or to merges it in one .

My code which i am using to create a `jTable` with two rows:

```
   // add header of the table
   String header[] = new String[] { "Prority", "Task Title", "Start",
        "Pause", "Stop", "Statulses" };

   // add header in table model     
   dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);

   // set model into the table object
   rstl_tbl2.setModel(dtm);

   if (this.rs_result.next()) {
     String  total = rs_result.getString("Total");
     // add row dynamically into the table      
     for (int count = 1; count <= 2; count++) {
       dtm.addRow(new Object[] { "data", "data", "data",
            "data", "data", "data" });
     }
   }
```

Comment: The easiest way is to just combine the data into a single string and add the string to the column.

Comment: @camickr  i tried but still columns rows remain , show me how with my code